# How to enable both form-based and OpenID login with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, openid

I want to allow users to either log into my Spring web application using the standard username / password approach or by using an OpenID Provider (e.g. Google). I tried to follow the various tutorials on the internet on that subject and got both OpenID and database username / password auth to work, but never together. As soon as I added the traditional username / password login, OpenID stopped working (When I click the OpenID login button I just get redirected to the login page again as if I were forbidden to access the /j_spring_openid_security_check page).

This is my spring security config page:

```
<security:http pattern="/login" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/polymer/**" security="none"/>

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login default-target-url="/"
                         login-page="/login"
                         authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                         username-parameter="username"
                         password-parameter="password"/>
    <security:openid-login user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:attribute-exchange identifier-match="https://www.google.com/.*">
            <security:openid-attribute name="email" type="http://axschema.org/contact/email" required="true" count="1"/>
            <security:openid-attribute name="firstname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" required="true" />
            <security:openid-attribute name="lastname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" required="true" />
            <security:openid-attribute name="fullname" type="http://axschema.org/namePerson/friendly" required="true" />
        </security:attribute-exchange>
    </security:openid-login>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />
    <security:remember-me token-repository-ref="tokenRepo" user-service-ref="userService" />
</security:http>

<bean id="webexpressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />

<bean id="tokenRepo" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl" />

<bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
</bean>
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="11"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And here is my login JSP page:

```
<%-- Username / password login form, works perfectly --%>
<c:url value="j_spring_security_check" var="targetUrl" />
<form action="${targetUrl}" method="post">
  <div>
    <label><spring:message code="login.username"/> <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><spring:message code="login.password"/> <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit"><spring:message code="login.submit" /></button>
  </div>
</form>

<%-- OpenID login form, doesn't work --%>
<c:url value='j_spring_openid_security_check' var="targetUrl"/>
<form action="${targetUrl}" method="post" id="openid-form">
  <h1>Sign in with Google</h1>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="verify" />
  <input type="hidden" id="openid_identifier" name="openid_identifier" value="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" />
  <input id="openid_submit" type="submit" value="Sign-In"/>
</form>
```

Thanks for any advice!

David

Comment: Are you able to fix this?

Comment: After deleting my local project copy and checking out the same version from SVN, the issue just disappeared. I don't know what caused it, but since it didn't come back, I regard it as resolved.